# Dynamic message on Salesforce1 above the feed/details/related tab

Tags: salesforce1-platform

I know fields are supported when you put them in the compact layout. But I want to include like a component. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compact layout is quite limited and you can only insert fields.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=compact_layout_create.htm&language=en_US

There is no other way to modify this region aside from selecting some fields to use. You would need to insert a Visualforce page into the record Detail section at the top of the layout if you want to insert a dynamic message / component that would be seen when the record is opened.